# Does await behave similarly in expressions and statements?

Tags: javascript

For statements, `await` can be thought of putting subsequent statements in a `.then`.

Does `await` work similarly for expressions?

For example, does the following block progress on resolution of `p1`, before blocking progress on resolution of `p2`?

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve()
const p2 = Promise.resolve()
return [await p1, await p2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` works with all expressions. Where `x` is an expression, `await x` is also a valid expression (which resolves asynchronously). That expression may or may not be a standalone statement as well.

But, keep in mind that `await`s are always processed *serially*. Your

```
return [await p1, await p2]`
```

will wait for `p1` to resolve, then for `p2` to resolve, then return an array containing those two resolved values. Usually, in this situation, you'd want to use `Promise.all` instead:

```
return Promise.all([p1, p2])
```

If you don't, you may run into an unhandled rejection - eg, if `p2` rejects *while it's not being `await`ed*:

```js
(async () => {
  const p1 = new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));
  const p2 = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(rej));
  return [await p1, await p2];
})()
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('error caught');
  });
  
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', () => {
  console.log('unhandled rejection; p2 was not being awaited at the time it rejected');
});
```

(also, if you have a function call that returns a Promise instead of already existing Promises, the `Promise.all` method will resolve more quickly, since it'll wait for the Promises to resolve in parallel)

Comment: Is the emission of `unhandledrejection` part of the spec and world-crucial, or is it just a host-provided informational notice that can usually be safely ignored? I ask because the `catch` still catches the error, and this is the only time I am aware of that the language emits an event like this.

Comment: The specification *does* say that environments should have [something which observes unhandled rejections](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-host-promise-rejection-tracker), but it doesn't specify what exactly the operation should do - it's up to the individual environment to decide.

Comment: In the code in the answer, the unhandled rejection occurs because the `p2` promise rejects *while it's not being `await`ed*. Then, *later*, the async function finishes resolving `p1`, gets to `p2`, sees that `p2` has rejected, and results in the async function rejecting, so control flow goes to the `catch`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the `await` expressions into individual statements:

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve()
const p2 = Promise.resolve()
const _temp1 = await p1
const _temp2 = await p2
return [_temp1, _temp2]
```

Then you can transform them into the equivalent `then` code:

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve()
const p2 = Promise.resolve()
return Promise.resolve(p1).then(_temp1 => {
    return Promise.resolve(p2).then(_temp2 => {
        return [_temp1, _temp2]
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the the question is asking

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I'm pretty sure it is, but let's wait for the OP to clarify :-)

Comment: Sure, I think he's asking rhetorically does it behave like this, not so much "how do I do this"